# Uncaught AssertionError: Env not set, aborting run cypress issue

Tags: cypress

Everytime i try to run my cypress test i am getting this error:

```
Uncaught AssertionError: Env not set,  aborting run

This error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.

We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.
```

Check your console for the stack trace or click this message to see where it originated from.

Maybe it is happening because when i run cypress open or run inside the folder, it opens like this and i have to manually select the test folder?

[image]

And when i do npm install, i get this error:

```
Required: {"node":">=8.9.4","npm":"~5.6.0"}
Actual:   {"npm":"6.4.1","node":"11.11.0"}
```

Comment: Three things ->  (1) Did you run `npx cypress open` from your project root folder? (2) Would be great if you could share the console logs (3) I don't think NPM version conflicts here, as the Node version is already satisfied.

Comment: @Kondasamy Jayaraman, npx cypress open gets me the same result, as the screenshot above

Comment: Are you running under root folder of your project?